# How to get refresh token of Box

Tags: c#, .net, upload, box-api, file-sharing

I have a C# desktop application which uploads files to **Box**,
it needs a Refresh token to generate the access token, but I'm unable to create the Refresh token programmatically. Created Refresh token from [This site](https://developers.box.com/oauth/)  and successfully uploaded the files to Box but this refresh token is expired after some minutes and throws an exception `Refresh token has expired`. I'm using the `box-csharp-sdk-v2`.

So I want to create a Refresh token using my client details or the api key programaticaly

Answer (score 4):

In order to work with Box OAuth2 tokens, you'll need to instantiate a `TokenProvider` using the API key and secret for your application:

```
// Instantiate a token provider.
var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider("apiKey", "apiSecret");
```

After sending the user through the OAuth2 workflow you will receive an authorization `code`. The `TokenProvider` can use this `code` to fetch the first access/refresh token pair:

```
// Fetch the initial access/refresh token pair
// You will want to persist these new values for later use.
var initialTokenPair = tokenProvider.GetAccessToken("code")
```

A new `Refresh` token is given to you every time you refresh the `Access` token. The `Refresh` token expires when it is used, or after ~60 days, whichever comes first.

```
// Refresh the token pair.
// You will want to persist these new values for later use.
var newTokenPair = tokenProvider.RefreshAccessToken("refreshToken");
```

I updated the *box-csharp-sdk-v2* [readme](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/blob/master/readme.markdown#usage-example) with the above example. I'm sorry that this wasn't made clear prior to now!

**EDIT**: Added example for fetching initial token pair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when i got refresh token i am able to generate the access token and is saved for future use, and with this access token i am able to upload files, but how can i generate the refresh token first time programatically??

Comment: When i upload a file to box and deleted it next time on wards the uploaded files will displayed only in the trash folder, i tried with different folder name and file name

Comment: *how can i generate the refresh token first time programatically?* I added an example for fetching the initial token pair using the OAuth2 authorization `code` provided by Box.

Comment: i am using a windows application developed using c#, "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=security_token" with this url i made a get request but i didn't get the "CODE".i also provided the redirect url in my box account and is http://localhost:8085/1 and i created a c# webserver to listen for the port 8085, but i didn't get any request regarding the code.. i am new to BOX, colud u plz explan the basic steps to get "CODE" from a c# windows application?

Comment: What does "After sending the user through the OAuth2 workflow" mean? Does it mean the user will be prompted to enter auth? If so, I guess one might call that programmatic access, but it's not what I typically think of programmatic. But maybe you have answered the letter of the question. I assume the OP is asking about automation; no user interaction. And, automation is what I am interested in.

Comment: @steve The 3-legged OAuth2 flow (described here) is still the correct thing to use for interacting with a Box user account on behalf of that user. In the last few years Box has released a [JWT Auth model](https://developer.box.com/guides/authentication/jwt/) for automation and server-to-server access.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
/*******************/
/** Authorization **/
/*******************/

// Create a OAuth2 access/refresh token provider using your API key/secret.
var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider("apiKey", "apiSecret");

// Fetch the initial token pair using the OAuth2 authorization code...
// You will want to persist these new values for later use.
var initialTokenPair = tokenProvider.GetAccessToken("code");

// You can also refresh the token pair.
// You will want to persist these new values for later use.
var newTokenPair = tokenProvider.RefreshAccessToken("refreshToken");

/*********************/
/** Box Interaction **/
/*********************/

// Instantiate a BoxManager client.
var boxManager = new BoxManager(newTokenPair.AccessToken);

// Create a new file in the root folder
boxManager.CreateFile(Folder.Root, "a new file.txt", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello, world!"));

// Fetch the root folder
var folder = boxManager.GetFolder(Folder.Root);

// Find a 'mini' representation of the created file among the root folder's contents
var file = folder.Files.Single(f => f.Name.Equals("a new file.txt"));

// Get the file with all properties populated.
file = boxManager.Get(file);

// Rename the file
file = boxManager.Rename(file, "the new name.txt");

// Create a new subfolder
var subfolder = boxManager.CreateFolder(Folder.Root, "my subfolder");

// Move the file to the subfolder
file = boxManager.Move(file, subfolder);

// Write some content to the file
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("goodbye, world!")))
{
    file = boxManager.Write(file, stream);
}

// Read the contents to a stream and write them to the console
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    boxManager.Read(file, stream);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("File content: '{0}'", reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

// Delete the folder and its contents
boxManager.Delete(subfolder, recursive: true);

As an enterprise administrator you can create a client and perform Box operations on behalf of another user.

// Instantiate a BoxManager client.
var boxManager = new BoxManager("AccessToken", onBehalfOf: "user@domain.com");

// ... do stuff as that user
// ... use your power only for awesome!
```

[Github](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/blob/master/readme.markdown#usage-example)